# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR After Installing SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl

After going through the process of renewing an expiring SSL certificate, I'm now getting "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" errors when viewing in Chrome. After hours of struggling, I've found a backup and replaced all of my cert files and conf files back to the way they were and am still getting the error. (My old certificate should still be valid for a few more days)

My error logs show a ton of entries including `Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01`.  Google searching on that brought me to posts describing how to check if the output on 443 is HTML.  I did a telnet session and can confirm that plaintext html is being sent back through port 443.

Running a2enmod ssl gives me "Module ssl already enabled".  That's all the posts I've found searching for that log result mention to check for.

Any other things to try to make sure SSL is running as it should?

**UPDATE**

Running `netstat -lnt` I get...

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

It's very hard for me to tell what's happening on port 80 with my site.  My domain is on the HSTS Preload List so it's kinda impossible for me to even try port 80.

**MORE IMPORTANT UPDATE**

The five million and eigth random thing I ended up trying ended up working, but I have no idea why.

All I did was change `<VirtualHost [my ip address]:443>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Can anyone explain why this has fixed things?  The version with my ip address was exactly what it was like before I started making changes last night.  I restored the file from backup.  I read in a few places that `NameVirtualHost` and `VirtualHost` can be useful.  But I never added or removed anything that included those commands.

Comment: Look in your logs.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned some of my conclusions were based off of what I found in the logs.  I have updated the post.  Any chance you can take another look at this question and/or remove downvote?

Comment: You have somehow disabled SSL protocol on port 443. Without seeing the configuration, we cannot tell what exactly is wrong.

Comment: You are most likely missing an `SSLEngine On` directive in the corresponding virtual host.

Answer (score 2):

> I did a telnet session and can confirm that plaintext html is being sent back through port 443.

It looks like you do not have an SSL enabled server listening on port 443. To get valid html back from *your site* via port 443 you have to set up an SSL connection and telnet doesn't do that. To check an SSL connection use

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

Note that some correctly configured servers may send back html to a non https connection on port 443 advising just that but yioou would I'm sure have noticed that e.g.

```
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That HTML is exactly what my server sent back via telnet.  Doing the command you suggested I got: `connect: Connection refused` `connect:errno=111`

Comment: Any other thoughts on what I can try?  If you're doubting my critical thinking right now it's because it's 3:30 am and I've been battling this for eight hours now.  I've love to be able to put this crisis to bed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might benefit from runnning a config check, and seeing what shows up:

`sudo apachectl configtest`

From your netstat output, httpd is not running.

Updated to account for response in comments:

OK, this seems like progress. Have you tried @[istheEnglishWay](https://serverfault.com/users/9517/is-the-english-way)'s suggestion, using `openssl s_client`?

Comment: `Sytnax OK`  Every time I do an apache restart it'll tell me if my syntax is wrong.  I rebooted the entire server and now ports 80 and 443 seem to be opened.  I updated my post.  Is there anything else you can think of?  I'm in a bit of desperation here.

Comment: Thank you for your attention so far!  I updated the question with some new developments.  Will continue to be eternally grateful to anyone who can help explain what's all happened in the past 12 hours!

Comment: So it is working? If so, great. It is a bit difficult to get a sense of what has happened from the various comments in this question, so I think it might be best to a) take a break, b) collect the logs and configs you believe are relevant to the issue, and c) open a new question to ask for help with the post-mortem. This question starts as being SSL related, veers into your apache server not running, and is solved by (it seems) tweaking VirtualHost addresses, and/or restoring a config backup (sounds like you've had a tough day) - no issue helping, but a clearer overview of would be useful